sitemap.xml not working after build in Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project where I need to generate a sitemap using sitemap.xml. The sitemap works perfectly in development, but after building the project for production, the /sitemap.xml URL returns no data.
I created sitemap.ts in /app
/app/sitemap.ts
import { MetadataRoute } from 'next'
import { getAllNews } from '../app/libs/api/news' 

export default async function sitemap(): Promise<MetadataRoute.Sitemap> {

  let news = await getAllNews();

  console.log(news)
  return [ ...news]
}


Are there any specific configurations or common issues related to static generation and sitemap generation in Next.js that I might be missing?

You can try to use the map function on the list of news feeds items.
const newsItems= news.map(item => ({
  url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/news/${item.slug}`,
  lastModified: item.updatedAt,
}));

return newsItems;

Make Sure that you have set the Environment variable fore the NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL depending upon your Operating System.
Please do share more detailed log. If problem presists.
